# My codes give an exception while using recursive function

Tags: java, exception, parameter-passing

i am trying to print numbers from 1 to 10 without using loops in java. When n+1 is passed to recursivefun method call in line 6,it works fine. But when n++ is passed,the code throws an error :/

```
public class PrintWithoutUsingLoops {

    public static void recursivefun(int n) {
        if (n <= 10) {
            System.out.println(n);
            recursivefun(n++);//an exception is thrown at this line.
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        recursivefun(1);
    }

}
```

Comment: So what's the exception? A stack overflow, by any chance? Have you stepped through the code in a debugger? What is the output, and what did you expect it to be? (You should be able to work out why it's failing just based on the output...)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
recursivefun(n++);
```

passes the original value of `n` to the recursive call (since you are using the post-increment operator), making this recursion infinite (since each recursive call gets the same value of `n`, which never reaches 11) and leading to `StackOverflowError`.

Change it to

```
recursivefun(n+1);
```

or

```
recursivefun(++n);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
recursivefun(n++);
```

This line means : call `recursivefun(n);` and then increment `n by 1` so you'll always call your fuction with `n=1` and caused a stackOverflow sure

So you need to increment n BEFORE all the function, you have some options :

```
recursivefun(n+1);
//-----------------------------
n++;
recursivefun(n);
//-----------------------------
recursivefun(++n); //pre-cincrement
```

Answer (score 1):

```
recursivefun(n++);
```

is a call with `post-increment`. Post increment is a mechanism which enlarges the value after it is read. In this case, you always pass 1.

You can use `pre-increment` which is `++n` which first: increments and then passes the value.

The exception you get is `StackOverflowError` which means, that the stack is full and JVM cannot store more calls on stack, so it won't be able to revert.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed both post and pre increment operators increments the value of a variable. Their behavior changes based on the context of the usage. Assume the following code:

For loop 1:
    for (i=0; i<10; i++)
    ...

For loop 2:
    for (i=0; i<10; ++i)
    ...

In both of the above statements, the for loop iterates 10 times irrespective of the increment style used. However consider the following code:

```
int x = 10;
int y = 20;
int z = x++ + ++y; // z = 10 + 21
System.out.println("x = " + x); // prints 11
System.out.println("y = " + y); // prints 21
System.out.println("z = " + z); // prints 31
```

Hence from your code it is evident that
    recursivefun(n++);

calls recursivefun with argument 1 infinitely. To avoid StackOverFlow error use either ++n or n+1.